# Parsing XML in GOlang

Tags: xml, go

I'm learning how to parse XML in GOlang using this  lesson: https://astaxie.gitbooks.io/build-web-application-with-golang/content/en/07.1.html
I succeeded with getting the result it's shown there:

```
{{ servers} 1 [{{ server} Shanghai_VPN 127.0.0.1} {{ server} Beijing_VPN 127.0.0.2}]
```

But how do I get the text from each field? When I'm printing, for example, v.Svs, I get

```
[{{ server} Shanghai_VPN 127.0.0.1} {{ server} Beijing_VPN 127.0.0.2}].
```

How do I receive **"Shanghai_VPN 127.0.0.1"**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using the objects from that example, to access the server name and IP of the first item of the list, you would use the following;

```
fmt.Println(v.Svs[0].ServerName)
fmt.Println(v.Svs[0].ServerIP)
```

In reality you should iterate over the array since you won't know how many objects there are. Here's a working example in play; https://play.golang.org/p/abnc9VaNlO

With iteration and the output formatting you have above that would be;

```
for _, srv := range v.Svs {
     fmt.Println(srv.ServerName + " " + srv.ServerIP)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works perfectly.

Comment: Since you're following that example, a nice practice recommended by Go is that you should ALWAYS map your XML/JSON to a well-known formatted struct in order to avoid array manipulation and reflection when working with collections.